# Excel 2016 - Find matching rows in column b, then sum Column C copy sum in Next Sheet Column A

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have a worksheet with the following 3 columns on Sheet 1:

```
ID  Week#   CodeCreateTime
16972   39  4
16980   39  4
19117   39  2
19146   40  2
22362   41  10
20890   41  5
```

I want to:

1. Find all items that match in the 'Week#' column
2. Sum their values in the 'CodeCreateTime' column
3. Copy the week# and summed value onto Sheet 2 in Column A.

For example, using the above data from Sheet 1, Sheet 2 would have the following values in column A and B:

```
A       B
39      10
40      2
41      15
```

Will a sumif(match) work?  I have been playing and not having luck.

Comment: The `SUMIF` function alone will already do the trick.

Comment: something like this : `=SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$6,Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$6)`

Comment: `=SUMIF(B:B,39,C:C)` would be an example for week 39 if you week is column B and your CodeCreateTime column is in column C.

Comment: You could also create a Pivot Table, although it is not dynamic like formulas.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - PivotTable could be made dynamic by basing it's data source on a dynamic named range :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Copy `Sheet1!B1:B6` to `Sheet2!A1:A6` 
2) [Remove Duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) on `Sheet2!A1:A6` 
3) In `sheet2!B2` type: `=SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7)` 
4) Drag down rest of rows in Sheet2

Comment: and File --> Save, so you don't lose all this work next time . :)

Comment: Thank you.  I tried using: =SUMIF(Sheet!$B$2:$B$6,A2,Sheet!$C$2:$C$6) and =SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$6,Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$6) but both give me 0.

Comment: @KatharinaDuBose - Sorry for my typo with `Sheet1`. I fully tested this and made one small edit that still equates to what you tried in your 2nd attempt and it worked fully for me. Make sure the data in sheet 1 is in the range specified in your formula.

Comment: Scott, yes!!!   This worked.  I have no idea what was happening, but it is now working.  Thank you so much!!  I will figure out how to close out this question and mark you as answered now.  Thank you!!!  Great ending to Friday!